# Outlook Add-in displayDialogAsync creating large popup in Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I was testing my Outlook Add-in on Outlook 2016 for Windows. The popup window opened by displayDialogAsync is significantly larger (about 30% or 40% larger) than the dimensions I provided in the options.

The other platforms I tested on (e.g. Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE10, IE11, Edge, Outlook 2016 for Mac, Outlook 2013 for Windows) open the popup with the correct size.

Are the dimensions of the popup window computed differently in Outlook 2016 for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Note it's not dimensions in pixels, but percentage of the screen size. Please refer to [displayDialogAsync API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). For example, width value "Defines the width of the dialog box as a percentage of the current display. The default value is 80%. The minimum resolution is 250 pixels.". Could this be the reason it's not behaving as you expected?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is something I considered, but: 1. I'm requesting a size > 250 pixels, and 2. I would expect that both IE11 and Outlook 2016 should open the same size dialog, since they're running on the same machine (and the screen size hasn't changed).

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. Would you mind providing us with your code along with screenshots of Outlook 2016 for Windows and another platform for comparison? Can you also give us the version of Outlook 2016 for Windows you are using? Thanks.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thank you for the answer. Is there any way to set the **position** of the window? My one appears at the top(vertical)-center(horizontal) position. I would like to have it in the center of the screen. Thank you!

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue, the dialog should open in the center. Would you mind providing us with your code along with screenshots? Can you provide the platform and version where are you repro-ing this (dialog aligned to top vertically)?